# how to copy data from Form to another Form using C#?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have got 2 Forms. The first one contain Data Grid View 1 and the second one contains Data Grid View 2 and Button. I want code, using C#, that when the user clicks on Button,
the data in the Data Grid View 2 is taken and displayed in Data Grid View 1. Can anyone can tell me how to do this in details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're really trying to do, I would suggest to make use of the [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class in both your forms, and bind them according to what you need with your [`DataGridview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/e0ywh3cz%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)s, then expose your [`BindingSource.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) through a Form property which will allow you to get and set the datasource outside of your Form, hence allowing you to change or update your `[DataGridView.DataSource`][4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property through this Form's property.